# error message while installing R Markdown on R version 4.0.1 on Windows

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am new to R and trying to install R Markdown on RStudio but it keeps giving me error messages eg

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘(tools)’ is not available (for R version 4.0.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have internet? try `install.packages("Rmarkdown", dep = TRUE)` you may also need to install latex for your system

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help.